# Loading 32 bit IE from SWT browser widget on 64 bit machine

Tags: eclipse, flash, 64-bit, swt

We developed an Eclipse plugin and tested & delivered on Win 32bit os. One of our view uses Broswer widget to load a Flash content. It works well on windows 32 bit.

Now planning to support Windows 64 bit. Unfortunately flash support for 64 bit is still in preview mode. SWT browser widget loads 64 bit IE though both version of IE (32 and 64 bit) available.

How can we try to enforce 32 bit IE in SWT browser widget?

I really appriciate the help.

Arun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better off asking this in the SWT forum on http://www.eclipse.org/forums/

But AFAIK, you can't.  On a 64-bit JVM, it will link in the 64 bit SWT which will link in the 64 bit IE libraries.

PW

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I too think so. I thought this is possible as we have 32 Bit IE in 64 bit machines. May be we can change the link to 32 bit IE.

Comment: You can run a 32-bit JVM with a 32-bit eclipse on a 64-bit machine ... that will link with 32-bit libraries if it can find them.